# Javascript won't take $_GET value from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

so I'd like to assign a url parameter value to jquery but it won't take it ..

```
  var product_id = '<?php echo $_GET["pID"]; ?>';
```

my function is below , document ready is included... just posted the relevant stuff

```
function sendOrderToServer() {
        var order = $(".sortable_table").sortable("serialize");
        var array_order = order.split("&");
        var product_id = '<?php echo $_GET["pID"]; ?>';
        alert(product_id);
        for (var i=0;i<array_order.length;i++){ 

            var id = array_order[i].split("=");
             id = id[1];
            var text_field_video = $("#products_video_sm_dynamic_"+ id).val();
            var text_field_video_caption = $("#products_video_sm_dynamic_"+ id +"_caption").val();
            var text_field_image = $("#products_image_sm_dynamic_"+ id).val();
            var text_field_image_caption = $("#products_image_sm_dynamic_"+ id +"_caption").val();
            var text_field_video_xl = $("#products_video_xl_dynamic_"+ id).val(); 
            var text_field_video_xl_caption = $("#products_video_xl_dynamic_"+ id +"_caption").val();
            var text_field_image_xl = $("#products_image_xl_dynamic_"+ id).val(); 

            if(text_field_video != undefined){

              var element = "products_video_sm_dynamic_" + id;
              var position = i + 1;
            }

            if(text_field_image != undefined){

              var element = "products_image_sm_dynamic_" + id ;
              var position = i + 1;
            }
            if(text_field_video_xl != undefined){

              var element2 = "products_video_xl_dynamic_" + id ;
              var position = i + 1;
            }
            if(text_field_image_xl != undefined){

              var element2 = "products_image_xl_dynamic_" + id ;
              var position = i + 1;
            }

            //alert(element);
            //alert("position is" + position);

            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
             url :'includes/insert_database.php', 
            data:{ position : position, element1:element , element2:element2}, 
           success: function(result){

                 alert(result);

            }
          });


        }


    }
```

Comment: It is a very bad idea to directly place a get value into javascript!

Comment: What does your rendered source code show as the value?

Comment: i just used hidden input type and it solved it

Comment: @JackFrankland there is no problem putting a php value into js.

Comment: You can do it yeah, but it makes it susceptible to xss, depends how much it matters though. Either way, a little sanitation would be wise.

Answer (score 0):

> http://example.com/yourpage.php?pID=%27%3B+alert%28%27OMG+I+just+totally+hacked+your+site%21%27%29%3B+%27

Try this instead:

```
var product_id = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['pID']); ?>
```